# How to open url in android auto

Tags: android, url, android-intent

Im trying to open an Url in Android Auto using the following code:

`val uri = Uri.parse("https://wwww.google.com") val intent = Intent(CarContext.ACTION_NAVIGATE, uri)                 carContext.startCarApp(intent)`

But I'm getting the following error:
androidx.car.app.host exception remote start car app call failed at androidx.car.app.utils.remoteutils.dispatchcartohostforresult(RemoteUtils.java:92)....

Someone is struggling with the same ?